# Is WiX Toolset Compatible with Windows 10

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2017, wix

We are going to be rolling out Win10 machines in the near future, so in preparation I am researching potential compatibility issues.  I use WiX as my installation framework, hence the question.  Is WiX fully compatible with VS2013 and VS2017 on the Win10 platform?

Comment: Just my 2 cents: If you are in a corporation and there is a custom action dll or similar that all packages use, I would be much more worried about that than WiX. Such custom code would be in all packages? Custom action failures on uninstall are particularly problematic - they can yield an "un-uninstallable" package. Will you be migrating machines or installing fresh? More test scenarios. Developer usually have test files / QA scripts that test custom action functionality that are great to obtain. Anyway, old news I guess...

Answer (score 1):

I've done Win 3.11 -> NT -> 2000 -> XP -> 7 -> 10 migrations and the problems are almost always application related not installer related. (Unless someone writes a garbage install.)

WiX 3.11 has no problems with Windows 10.   We currently have around 120,000 windows 10 devices deployed and I believe 1 kiosk type role that is still on Windows 7.   A bunch of corp desktops are still on Windows 7 still but those are just the stragglers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is totally compatible on Win10 platform. I have been using Wix installer (v3.11) on VS2015 for a year. All you need to do is -> download and install the proper extension for your Visual Studio version from the following URL: http://wixtoolset.org/releases/. Then, download and install the version you want (stable ones are v3.11 and v3.10). That's it!